# What is the difference between Visual Keyframes and Baking Animations

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes

Recently I have been trying to animate some certain things for a game I'm writing. However, my game engine(Not the blender game engine) only takes rigged animation (without any bone constraints). So to import in the animations I have to use the Bake Action function, but every time I bake an action It would make another action and then I would have to rename everything.

But then I discovered what Visual Keying is and now I am wondering if I can just use visual keyframes instead of normal keyframes so that I don't have to Bake the action later.